# Como comparo dos Arrays mientras que uso el polimorfismo?

Tags: java, poo

tengo cuatro clases incluyendo la clase main.

1. la clase Employee.
2. la clase Salesman.
3. la clase Manager.
4. y por ultimo la clase Main.

y estoy realizando dos arrays con dos puestos cada uno para introducir en la posicion 0 de ambos arrays, objetos de la clase Salesman y en la 1 objetos de la clase Manager.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee[] arr1= new Employee[2];
    Employee[] arr2= new Employee[2];
    
    arr1[0]= new Salesman("1234", "David",2,9,6,8);
    arr1[1]= new Manager ("1234", "David",3,9,567, true);
    arr2[0]= new Salesman("1234", "David",2,9,6,8);
    arr2[1] =new Manager ("1234", "David",3,9,567, true);
    
    System.out.println("Arr:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr1[i]+"\n");
        System.out.println(arr2[i]+"\n");
    }
    
    boolean answer=Arrays.equals(arr1,arr2);
    System.out.println("arr1 y arr2 son iguales: "+answer);
    
}
```

y al comparar me sale que es false, a pesar que sean todos los valores iguales.
trate de usar la función de:

```
public  boolean equals(Object o)
{
    
    Employee E = (Employee)o;
    etc...
 }
```

pero no se como se hace con el polimorfismo.

Answer (score 0):

En la case `Employee` puedes sobre escribir el método `equals`.
Aquí va un ejemplo de como puedes comparar:

```
public class Employee {
    String name="";
    int age = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // If the object is compared with itself then return true   
        if (o == this) { 
            return true; 
        }

        if (!(o instanceof Employee)) { 
            return false; 
        }

        Employee c = (Employee) o;

        // Aquí haces la comparación que necesites.
        return this.name.compareTo(c.name)==0 && this.age==c.age;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que el método `Arrays.equals` funcione, debes tener en cuenta que el método `equals` del tipo base debe estar bien implementado, pues la comparación de vectores se realiza en base a este método, de la siguiente forma:

```
// Para cada par de elementos de sendos vectores, con los mismos índices
if (e1 == null ? e2 == null : e1.equals(e2))
```

Ahora bien, para lidiar con el polimorfismo al re definir el método `equals` de la clase `Object` debes evitar el uso de `instanceof`, y hacerlo pensando en todos los casos que se pueden dar. Además, habrá que re definir el método en la clase padre `Employee` y en las clases hijas `Salesman` y `Manager`, añadiendo condiciones a la implementación base.

Para empezar, piensa en la clase `Employee`.

Teniendo en cuenta que `this` hace referencia a un objeto (invocador) no nulo (si el invocador fuese nulo la llamada al método lanza un `NullPinterException`), se dan los siguientes casos:

- Si el objeto pasado como argumento es nulo (`o == null`), no puede ser igual al invocador, ya que el último (`this`) no es nulo, por lo que se devuelve `false`.
- Si el invocador se compara consigo mismo (`o == this`), se devuelve `true`, ya que cualquier objeto es igual a sí mismo.
- Si el invocador y el parámetro son de clases distintas en tiempo de ejecución, teniendo en cuenta polimorfismo (`o.getClass() != getClass()`), entonces no pueden ser iguales, por lo que se devuelve `false`.
- Si el invocador y el parámetro son de la misma clase en tiempo de ejecución, teniendo en cuenta polimorfismo, entonces podemos realizar un *casting* (sin que salte un `ClassCastException`) y comparar los atributos que correspondan, según la igualdad que queramos definir, teniendo en cuenta que si los atributos son objetos, necesitaremos recurrir a su método `equals`, y si son de un tipo de dato primitivo, basta con el operador de igualdad (`==`).

```
public class Employee {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (o.getClass() != getClas()) return false;
        Employee e = (Employee) o;
        // Ejemplo, depende de los atributos
        return name.equals(e.name) && edad == e.edad && ... ;
    }
}
```

Como nota aclaratoria: comparar clases en el método `equals` mediante `instanceof` es una mala práctica. Para empezar porque es un operador que comprueba si un objeto está en la jerarquía de herencia a partir de la clase indicada, pero no indica la clase del objeto.

```
Salesman s = new Salesman();

// La condición es verdadera, obviamente, porque s es una instancia de Salesman
if (s instanceof Salesman) ;

// También es true porque s es un tipo de Employee, o mejor dicho, porque s es un Salesman,
// que es un tipo de Employee, por lo que s también es una instancia de Employee
if (s instanceof Employee) ;
```

En segundo lugar, te puede obligar a que el padre conozca qué clases heredan de ella, lo que es bueno evitar.

```
// Posible comprobación de tipos dentro de Employee.equals
if (e instanceof Salesman) hazAlgo();
else if (e instanceof Manager) hazOtraCosa();
else otraAccion();
```

Si lo hace así, va a funcionar, pero en el momento en que crees una nueva clase que herede de `Employee` estás obligado a modificar el método de `Employee` donde hayas utilizado este análisis de casos basado en `instanceof`. Heredar de una clase en ningún caso debe obligar a la clase padre a ser modificada.

Por tanto, he propuesto el uso del método `getClass` porque devuelve la clase a la que pertenece un objeto, en tiempo de ejecución, teniendo en cuenta polimorfismo.

```
// La variable e fue declarada como de clase Employee,
// pero se le asigna un objeto de clase Salesman
Employee e = new Salesman();
e.getClass();         // Devuelve una referencia a la clase Salesman
e = new Manager();    // La variable e ahora hace referencia a un objeto Manager
e.getClass();         // Devuelve una referencia a la clase Manager
```

Finalmente, si una clase hereda de `Employee` y define atributos nuevos que quieres tener en cuenta en la igualdad o desigualdad mediante el método `equals`, debes volver a re definir este método en la clase hija, haciendo uso de la implementación del padre (`Employee`).

En este caso, tenemos que:

- Si la comprobación de la clase padre devuelve `false`, devolveremos también `false`, ya que hay atributos que son diferentes y no hace falta comprobar los propios de la clase hija.
- Si la comprobación del padre devuelve `true`, entonces podemos realizar un *casting* a la clase hija y comprobar además los nuevos atributos, para terminar de extender la igualdad. Esto es así porque puede que los atributos del objeto que hereda de la clase padre sean iguales entre dos objetos, pero que se diferencien solo en atributos de la clase hija.

```
public class Salesman extends Employee {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // El código de la clase padre comprueba nulo, identidad y clase
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        Salesman s = (Salesman) o;
        // Ejemplo con un hipotético atributo de Salesman
        return ventas == s.ventas && ... ;
    }
}
```

Finalmente, si has re definido el método `equals` debes re definir el método `hashCode` para que vaya acorde con la definición del método `equals` de la clase donde lo hayas re definido.